# dojo how to overwrite event handler

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

Currently dojo uses `on` method to connect event to handler.

```
btn = new Button();
btn.on('click', function () {console.log('do something');});
```

this will call the attached function when the button gets clicked.

however, according to the documents, removing existing handlers should be done in the following way

```
handler = btn.on('click', function () {console.log('do something');});
handler.remove();
```

this is not the way I want to remove event handler.

I do not store the handler reference anywhere. But I want to add a new 'click' event by doing

```
btn.on('click', function () {console.log('do something different');});
```

so that it replaces the existing 'click' event handler and add a new one.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: A quick look around the Dojo source code makes me suspect it's not possible. It probably wouldn't be too difficult to write your own wrapper around `on` which could store the handlers in a sort of map, but this has its own problems (namely, anything you're storing a reference to can't be garbage collected). You'll probably need to find a way to just store the handler.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Thanks for the comment. since storing option is not impossible I'll just store references then implement wrapper later stage when it's necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, the framework tells you to do it in the way by creating a reference to the event handler. This is similar to how other frameworks like jQuery work.

jQuery has of course a mechanism to remove all event handlers by using the `off()` function, but that's not available in Dojo either. Like Chris Hayes suggested in the comments, you can implement such a feature by yourself, either by wrapping it inside another module, or by using aspects on the `dojo/on` module.

For example, you can wrap it inside a new module:

```js
// Saving the event handlers
var on2 = function(dom, event, callback) {
    on2.handlers = [];

    if (on2.handlers[event] === undefined) {
        on2.handlers[event] = [];   
    }
    var handler = on(dom, event, callback);
    on2.handlers[event].push({
        node: dom,
        handler: handler
    });
    return handler;
};
// Off functionality
lang.mixin(on2, on, {
    off: function(dom, event) {
        if (this.handlers[event] !== undefined) {
            array.forEach(this.handlers[event], function(handler) {
                if (handler.node === dom) {
                    handler.handler.remove();   
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And then you can use it:

```
on2(dom.byId("test"), "click", function() {
    console.log("test 1 2 3"); // Old event handler
});
on2.off(dom.byId("test"), "click"); // Remove old event handlers
on2(dom.byId("test"), "click", function() {
    console.log("test 4 5 6"); // New event handler
});
```

This should work fine, as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X7H3F/

Answer (score -1):

```
btn = new Button();
btn.attr('id','myButton');
query("#myButton").on('click', function () {console.log('do something');});
```

Do the same thing when you want to replace your handler. Like,

```
query("#myButton").on('click', function () {console.log('do something different');});
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Are you sure this works? It looks like it's executing both event handlers, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Yj5em/. As far as I know the `dojo/NodeList::on()` function also returns an array of event handlers that have to be removed first, which means you need a reference to it.